# How do I move a an object without stutter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I want to move in a certain direction, there's a stutter before it moves continuously until I let go of the key. I'm not sure how to explain it but I want it to move, smoothly in a direction without the initial stutter.

I tried searching this up, but I don't really know how to describe this problem and all tutorials I found were doing the same thing.

```
        if (key.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            picPlayer.Top -= 5;
        }

        if (key.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            picPlayer.Top += 5;
        }
```

It sorta looks like this

*initial keypress* → *pause* → → → → → → → → → → → → →
                        < Continuous movement

Hopefully that made sense

EDIT: (I'm using visual studios)

Comment: Are you using Unity?

Comment: Sorry I left that out, I'm using Visual Studios

Comment: Sorry I saw you are using VisualStudio, but what are you using. What is creating the stutter effect. Purely c# shouldn't create a stutter effect. If it is basic c# do you have a git branch? Have you tried it with a different PC (is it a pc problem not a code problem)

Comment: @Pretzel, how are you reading the key codes? It sounds like you are experiencing the pause before the keyboard subsystem kicks of a repeat key press. If that is the case you are using the wrong approach to reading the keyboard, but just a guess without more of the code.

Comment: @Monofuse It's definitely my code because my PC (I'm on my laptop currently) does this too. I also am very new to coding so I don't really know how to elaborate on what I am using but I'm using WindowsFormsApp .netFramwork?

Comment: Which libraries are you using?

Comment: @Chris Taylor Oh wait, you're probably right, but even then I don't really know how I should approach this because I've tried doing something with timers and it didn't work well.

Comment: @Monofuse Visual C#? I'm sorry if I'm not answering your question because I'm really clueless about all of this

Comment: @Pretzel, are you building a WPF app or WinForms?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I'm building a Window Forms App

Comment: OK, so what you might want to do is use System.Windows.Input to check the Keyboard state and use that to update your player. You can use a Task to run your game loop that checks the state and updates the player. I will see if I can put a simple sample together for you.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Winforms animation will never be really smoth, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example that might help you get started. You will need to add a reference to two assembles for this to work.

**Step 1.**
In `Solution Explorer` right click on `References` and select `PresentationCore` and `WindowsBase` to add these references to your project.

**Step 2.**
Add a `Timer` to your form and set the properties as follows `(Name) = timer`, `Interval = 16`. On the events tab set the `Tick` event handler to `timer_Tick` (double clicking will do that automatically.

**Step 3.**
Here is the code for the form.

You should also add an event handler for `Load` event on the Form, here the handler is called `Form1_Load`. The code also assumes you have a control called `picPlayer` on the form, probably a PictureBox control in your case.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MovePlayerDemo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.W))
            {
                picPlayer.Top -= 5;
            }

            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
            {
                picPlayer.Top += 5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should get you started. Basically what is happening is every timer tick you are checking the keyboard state and then updating the game objects appropriately. Note, there are better ways to do this "gameloop" but for now this will keep it simple and you will not need to worry about updating controls across threads etc.